# How to make v-stepper-step size large in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-stepper

[image: This is the Stepper image . View it !!]

How can I change this icon/ step circle size in v-stepper ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::v-deep .v-stepper__step__step {
     width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Matthew. Is there a way to make the icons inside the step large?

Comment: I had to use .v-stepper__step__step { width: 40px; height: 40px;  } , without ::v-deep  .

Comment: @NamudaraAbeysinghe Sorry I left out some information here - so if you're using SASS you must use ::v-deep to set the style. Without SASS use >>>. In either case the style tag must be scoped. 

The third option is to use the exact class selector as you have above without a scoped style attribute